# Pinch Zoom into multiple Images on a single view (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm a little confused on how I can properly scroll into images, when I'm using multiple UIScrollViews

I have

- pinchScrollView1
- pinchScrollView2
- image1
- image2

  ```
  pinchScrollView1.minimumZoomScale=1.0
  pinchScrollView1.maximumZoomScale=6.0
  pinchScrollView2.minimumZoomScale=1.0
  pinchScrollView2.maximumZoomScale=6.0

  func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
  {

  return self.image1
  }
  ```

So this works great for the first image, and I thought perhaps I could check to see which scrollview was focused, then return the corresponding image like

```
 if pinchZoomScroll1.isFocused {
      return self.image1
 }
 else { return self.image2}
```

but this of course, is not properly zooming the correct image

I'm thinking it has to do with me setting both UIScrollView's delegates in the storyboard, but i'm a little lost on how to basically have two different "viewForZooming" functions, for each respective ScrollView.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out myself, here's what I did!

I removed the delegates from the storyboard

```
 self.pinchZoomScroll1.delegate = self
 self.pinchZoomScroll2.delegate = self
 pinchZoomScroll1.tag = 1
 pinchZoomScroll2.tag = 2

  func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
  {
    if scrollView.tag == 1 {
       return self.image1
    }
    else {
       return self.image2
    }

}
```

Feel free to let me know if there's a better approach, but it's working! Hope this helps someone else.